# Am I getting the definition of these topological concepts right?

Tags: general-topology

Now I won't use a "textbook" definition. I will just describe it.

Interior Point - If I have a set S and theirs a point in this set S, then it is an interior point if I can surround it with an epsilon ball.

Limit Point - A limit point is the idea that if you surround a point with an epsilon ball and other points are in the ball from the graph, then the point you chose is a limit point.

Quotient Space and Closure are ones I am still a little unsure of.

Comment: You got the idea but you don't always have a topology that is induced by a metric. So you cannot talk about "epsilon balls".

Comment: Besides, in my opinion, it is better to use a textbook definition rather than describing things. But if you want to get the intuition, you can work on the examples.

Comment: How would you describe the closure of a set?

Answer (score 2):

You’ve omitted something very important from your description of an interior point of a set: $x$ is an interior point of $S$ if some $\epsilon$-ball about $x$ **is contained in** $S$. (You may have meant this, but you didn’t actually say it.)

I suspect that you have more or less the right understanding of a limit point of a set, though you haven’t expressed it very well; in particular, the term *graph* is out of place here. Where you have *graph*, you really mean the set $S$: a point $x$ is a limit point of $S$ if every $\epsilon$-ball about $x$ contains other points of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

A point is in the closure of a set if every ball containing the point meets the set.